# python Returning data from a threaded def

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a bit of code that gets the title of a .MP3 file

```
def getTitle(fileName):
    print "getTitle"
    audio = MP3(fileName)

    try:
        sTitle = str(audio["TIT2"])
    except KeyError:
        sTitle = os.path.basename(fileName)

    sTitle = replace_all(sTitle) #remove special chars

    return sTitle
```

I would call this function with

```
sTitle = getTitle("SomeSong.mp3")
```

To solve another problem I wanted to spawn this on its own thread so I altered my call to

```
threadTitle = Thread(target=getTitle("SomeSong.mp3"))
threadTitle.start()
```

This correctly calls the function and solves my other problem, but now I can't figure out how to get the return value of sTitle from the function into Main.

Comment: Note that your `Thread` constructor call is wrong.  The `target` parameter must be a callable, but you assign the return value of a `getTitle()` call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would make a new object that extends thread so that you can get anything you want out of it at any time.

```
from threading import Thread

class GetTitleThread(Thread):        

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.sTitle = None
        self.fileName = fileName
        super(GetTitleThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print "getTitle"
        audio = MP3(self.fileName)

        try:
            self.sTitle = str(audio["TIT2"])
        except KeyError:
            self.sTitle = os.path.basename(self.fileName)

        self.sTitle = replace_all(self.sTitle) #remove special chars


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = GetTitleThread('SomeSong.mp3')
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print t.sTitle
```

Comment: Why is `sTitle` a class variable?

Comment: It is now an instance variable, which is more suited. Thanks!

Comment: Now I like it, +1 :) BTW, the initialisation of `sTitle` is lacking a `self`.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks. I suppose it wouldn't have mattered TOO much!

Comment: Im new to python and very new to threading.  What does t.join() do?

Comment: For some reason the value being returned is always None.  When looking at my output I am getting an error "NameError: global name 'fileName' is not defined" on the line audio = mp3(fileName).  I double checked the spelling and case of everything and it looks correct to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: I changed fileName to self.fileName and it works.  Thank you very much

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join This waits for the thread to finish. Missed that also, fixed!

Answer (score 15):

One way to do it is to use a wrapper storing the result:

```
def wrapper(func, args, res):
    res.append(func(*args))

res = []
t = threading.Thread(
    target=wrapper, args=(getTitle, ("SomeSong.mp3",), res))
t.start()
t.join()
print res[0]
```

Comment: That's correct but he will also need to wait for the spawned thread to be done.

Answer (score 2):

This one comfortably makes any function running in a thread taking care of its return value or exception:

```
def threading_func(f):
    """Decorator for running a function in a thread and handling its return
    value or exception"""
    def start(*args, **kw):
        def run():
            try:
                th.ret = f(*args, **kw)
            except:
                th.exc = sys.exc_info()
        def get(timeout=None):
            th.join(timeout)
            if th.exc:
                raise th.exc[0], th.exc[1], th.exc[2] # py2
                ##raise th.exc[1] #py3                
            return th.ret
        th = threading.Thread(None, run)
        th.exc = None
        th.get = get
        th.start()
        return th
    return start
```

### Usage Examples

```
def f(x):
    return 2.5 * x
th = threading_func(f)(4)
print("still running?:", th.is_alive())
print("result:", th.get(timeout=1.0))

@threading_func
def th_mul(a, b):
    return a * b
th = th_mul("text", 2.5)

try:
    print(th.get())
except TypeError:
    print("exception thrown ok.")
```

Comment: nice and handy decorator!